# Editable, expanding input list control for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, user-input, user-experience

We're looking for a certain type of control, preferably with a Bootstrap implementation. We don't believe it's really uncommon, but we might be wrong.

It's essentially a listbox, but also:

- It's like an editable combobox, but without a dropdown.
- Like a tag input/pillbox, but vertical, with a more traditional style, and *directly* editable.
- Like an expanding grid, but with a single column.
- Like a series of vertically attached text input field boxes, on steroids.
- Like a text area, but properly structured and expanding.

The ultimate goal is to be able to quickly and efficiently input a bunch of values (phone numbers, ...) without leaving the keyboard, while allowing the user to edit or remove existing values painlessly.  (The form is relatively large and part of a LOB application.)

1. Does this control have a name?
2. Does anyone know of a Bootstrap plugin that provides such a control?
3. If not, then we're not exactly sure about how to proceed, would you have any pointers for us so that we can implement this in a straightforward way? (Is it a good idea to start with a series of text input fields for example?)

Details:

1. It's essentially a list,
2. It starts as something that looks very much like a simple text input field,
3. When the user presses *ENTER*, a new row is added below and the cursor is moved to it (the list expands dynamically),
4. When the user presses *TAB*, the cursor is moved to the next control,
5. (Optional) When the user presses the *UP* or *DOWN* arrow key, the cursor jumps in the previous or next element, respectively,
6. Each row is directly editable (the user can click **inside** any of them and change any character, even in the middle, thus without deleting the element first),
7. (Optional) There can only be one empty row at the end,
8. (Optional) If the user focuses another control (for example by pressing *TAB*) or another element (for example by using the arrow keys or by clicking), the current element is removed if it's empty,
9. (Optional) In addition to pressing *ENTER* when the cursor is in the last field, the user can press a button to add a new empty element if the last element is not empty,
10. There is only one column (no need for a column header),
11. (Optional) An inline label should be displayed in the last element if it's empty,
12. There is a button next to each element that allows the user to remove them,
13. (Optional) When the user presses *DELETE* twice at the end of an element, the focused element is removed (it must be pressed twice so that a user who keeps the button pressed to delete a bunch of characters doesn't remove the element by accident if that wasn't her intention -- this requirement can be formulated in other ways),
14. (Optional) The user can undo a delete operation,
15. (Optional) If the number of elements exceeds a certain limit, a scroll bar appears and the height of the control is fixed at that limit,
16. (NTH) If the number of elements exceeds a second (normally higher) limit, the list is paginated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As I don't know any control that suits your needs, I'll try to suggest some implementation options:**

---

**Contenteditable:**

Take a look at the `contenteditable` attribute - [**demo here**](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable).

This won't match all your requirements (point 12 is the main blocker here), but it's pretty nice OOTB, and (according to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)) cross-browser.

The demo provided above may be a good starting point for your own solution.

---

**One input per line:**

The other approach will be to use one input for each of the lines. 
I've provided [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R2tJX/) that adds "new line" as enter is pressed.

Although this implementation will also need a bit of boxing with keyboard events, this *one-element-per-line* model seems to better reflect your bussiness needs and is pretty flexible.
I'd be afraid about performance with bigger data sets, though.

This can be also mixed with `contenteditable` approach (e.g. list of editable `<li>` elements), but it doesn't seem to bring in any benefits. It even brings some problem, because `contenteditable` won't restrict number of lines by default; with regular `input`, you have a guarantee that one element contains one line.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of using this, that's certainly creative. I guess we could style list items the way we want. I'm a bit worried though that we would run in the same issues as a newline-delimited text area in that we would have difficulties in tracking which elements correspond to which data records. For example; imagine a user removes an element and edits the next one. When we retrieve the data, the situation is ambiguous: Did the user remove the first one and edit the second one, or did the user edit the first one and remove the second one? Anyway, I'll look into it ASAP.

Comment: I assume that one of usage scenarios is that you start with a non-empty list? I understood that's the case you're worried about. I must've missed that. In that case probably it'll be better to implement every line as separate text input and let the jQuery do the rest... or implement more sophisticated edit control with `contenteditable` - which may not be possible at all.

Comment: Indeed, the control would be used for all of CRUD operations. I guess we dreamed it up. I did look into the use of `contenteditable`, I think it's technically possible to track the inputs (for example for data-binding) simply by listening to DOM events, but for some reason I'm reluctant to dive in there. Maybe it's just me, but it seems the `contenteditable` attribute was really intended to help implement rich text editing; using it for anything else doesn't feel too right, at least right now. For example even with `li` elements you'd have to worry about newlines (shift+return).

Comment: See my edited answer. The second approach is more flexible (and shift + return won't break anything...).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we were thinking about, and this is an excellent starting point. Thank you!